# hover on div 1 show cycle all slide 1, hover on 2 show cycle all slide 2

Tags: jquery, hover, cycle, jquery-cycle

I've created a slideshow of testimonials, and above are 3 sections relating to 3 categories related to the slides.

So I have div1 and slide1, div2 and slide2, div3 and slide3.

I'm still pretty new to jquery—how would I say:

"hover this div1, pause cycle all on slide1"

```
 $('.section-testimonials').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    speed: 1000,
    containerResize: 0,
    timeout: 9000
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well those `<div>`'s just need to be placed as a Nav or Paging for jQuery cycle.

NOTE** make sure you are using cycle-all FULL not LITE

```
$('#slideshow').cycle({ 
    speed:       200, 
    timeout:     3000, 
    pager:      '#nav', // <-- point to the wrapper around your div's
    pagerEvent: 'mouseover', // <-- this causes the Pause (keeps it paused the whole time you're hovered)
    pauseOnPagerHover: true 
});​
```

http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/pagerHover.html

Comment: Do the pagers all need to have the same div classes? (in this case they all have the same class 'feature' but have other classes as well—maybe cauasing a conflict for this not to work.

Comment: You'd have to read more about the plugin, http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/. I'm not sure, haven't used it in a while!

Comment: AHHH!!!! Had to use the full version of cycle all, rather then the LITE version, works like a charm.